# Why is my smiley parsing code calling native javascript functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, native

I'm writing a smiley parsing function for my website. What I'm trying to accomplish is to transform certain strings, e.g. `":)"` into an image like this: [image]

Or here's the actual html as an example:

```
":)" ===> <img src="images/smilies/smile.png" />
```

My function does what it's meant to do, but it is also parsing native javascript function names! What I mean by this, is if I type a comment containing the strings `"push"` , `"pop"` , or `"some"` (there are probably loads others) my function will parse those strings into invalid images like this:

[image]

Here is an html string showing this:

```
<img src="images/smilies/function some() { [native code] }" alt="">
```

This results in a 404 not found error in the browser console.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Why is this happening? I'm not doing anything too unusual in my code as you can see here:

```
        function parse_new_comment(commentElem){
            $(commentElem).html(parse_comment($(commentElem).text()));
        }


        function parse_comment(comment){
            var formatted_comment = "";

            var smilies = new Array();
            smilies[":)"] = "smile.png";
            smilies[":D"] = "smile-big.png";
            smilies[":p"] = "tongue.png";
            smilies["[sheep]"] = "sheep.png";
            smilies["<3"] = "love.png";
            smilies["[love]"] = "love.png";

            var words = comment.split(" ");

            for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
                if(smilies[words[i]] !== undefined){
                    formatted_comment += ' <img src="images/smilies/'+smilies[words[i]]+'" alt="" />';
                }else{
                    formatted_comment += ' ' + words[i];
                }
            }
            return formatted_comment;
        }
```

I have a feeling that this line of the code is causing the problem `if(smilies[words[i]] !== undefined){`, as `push` and `pop` are array functions, i'm not too sure though... I would appreciate if someone could suggest any ideas on why my function is failing.

Oh I forgot to mention, my page uses ajax to do everything, so new comments are parsed by calling the function like this:

```
parse_new_comment($("#comment_343"));
```

Thank you.

Comment: You should declare "smilies" like this: `var smilies = {};` because you're not using it as an Array anyway.

Comment: You shouldn't be using an `Array` for this. A map (associative array, hash table, dictionary, whatever you wanna call it) would be fine, sadly Javascript confuses that with objects, so an object (`{}`) will have to do. Note that this doesn't solve the actual problem, though it may solve other potential problems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check that the object has the property itself and not that the object's property is undefined. This can be done using [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty).

```
if(smilies.hasOwnProperty(words[i])){
```

Instead of

```
if(smilies[words[i]] !== undefined){
```

Also, since you are not using `smilies` as an array I agree with Pointy's comment that it should be declared as an object. It is worth mentioning that when you attach keys to an `Array` in JavaScript they are only considered array indexes if [they can be seen as unsigned integers](http://es5.github.com/#x15.4).

```
var smilies = {};//short for new Object();
smilies[":)"] = "smile.png";
smilies[":D"] = "smile-big.png";
smilies[":p"] = "tongue.png";
smilies["[sheep]"] = "sheep.png";
smilies["<3"] = "love.png";
smilies["[love]"] = "love.png";
```

You might be interested in using literal syntax as suggested by the answer Explosion Pills suggested. Just to clarify, using `hasOwnProperty` is still required.

Comment: ... or just use an `Object` instead of an `Array`.

Comment: This answer is still valuable, as even with object his code would try to find a "toString" smiley image :-)

Comment: @JanDvorak That still wouldn't completely fix the problem. `toString` and other object prototype methods would be included

Comment: @JanDvorak For example a["hasOwnProperty"] is still defined, which might be problematic in OP's case

Comment: what about `typeof a[key] == "string"` ? It's not like `Object`s inherit any strings :-)

Comment: I actually have a follow up question. Wouldn't it be more efficient if @JoelMurphy used regular expressions and `replace`? Wouldn't that avoid this issue entirely?

Comment: @Rikonator I was looking to fix OP's code, it is possible to use regular expressions to solve this issue, however, to people who are unfamiliar with regular expressions it would probably be confusing. As for speed, I'm really not sure. It's probably relatively simple to create a perf

Comment: a HUGE thank you to everyone here for their input. I was shocked when I came back after 5 minutes to find all these replies. I have learned something new today, which is to be overly conscious with JavaScript security, just as I am with PHP :) I have re-written my code to use a smiley object, as well as changed the line that I thought was causing problems with: if(smilies.hasOwnProperty(words[i]) && (typeof smilies[words[i]]) == 'string'){ - problem solved! Thank you guys again :D

Comment: As for the regular expressions comment; I have used them before to do very simple validation checks, but I find it hard to remember what everything does. Maybe one day I will finally remember how to use them :p

Answer (score 4):

I'd just do :

```
function parse_new_comment(commentElem) {
    commentElem.html(parse_comment(commentElem.text()));
}

function parse_comment(comment) {
    return comment.replace(/(\:\)|\:D|\:p|\[sheep\]|\<3|\[love\])/gi, function (match) {
        var smilies = {
                ":)": "smile.png",
                ":D": "smile-big.png",
                ":p": "tongue.png",
                "[sheep]": "sheep.png",
                "<3": "love.png",
                "[love]": "love.png"
        }
        return '<img src="images/smilies/' + smilies[match] + '" alt="" />';
    });
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6bwZt/)

Comment: +1 for your coding method. I am not very experienced with regular expressions, as I find it hard to remember what everything does. I will definitely keep this function in mind for the future though, as I'm looking to make some further code improvements when I have finished developing my website and I like how clean this code is.

Comment: +1 For different approach, it is worth noting you can create the RegExp yourself dynamically by escaping and .join(")|(") ing the Object.Keys of smilies.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use an `Array` and access it like an object.  Use an object.  What you are seeing is behavior from accessing the Array methods using object-access syntax.  You should only use numeric keys to access arrays.

```
var smilies = {
    ":)": "smile.png",
    ":D": "smile-big.png",
};
```

...and so on.

You should be able to keep the rest of your code the same.

Answer (score 2):

I would use an implementation which dynamically creates a regular expression (which is also likely to be much faster):

```
RegExp.escape = function(text) {
  return text.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
};

function SmileyParser(smiles) {
    var smilepatterns = [], k;
    for (k in smiles) {
        if (smiles.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
            smilepatterns.push(RegExp.escape(k));
        }
    }
    this.smiles = smiles;
    this.re_smiles = RegExp("(^|\\s)("+smilepatterns.join("|")+")($|\\s)", 'g');
}
SmileyParser.prototype.replace = function (text) {
    var smiles = this.smiles;
    function replacer(m, p1, p2, p3) {
        console.log(m);
        return p1
        +"<img src='/images/smiles/"+smiles[p2]+"'>"
        +p3;
    }
    return text.replace(this.re_smiles, replacer);
};
```

Then use like this:

```
var smiles = {
                ":)": "smile.png",
                ":D": "smile-big.png",
                ":p": "tongue.png",
                "[sheep]": "sheep.png",
                "<3": "love.png",
                "[love]": "love.png"
        };

var sp = new SmileyParser(smiles);
var text = 'This comment parses my smiley fine :)';
var newtext = sp.replace(text);
```

`newtext` will be:

```
This comment parses my smiley fine <img src='/images/smiles/smile.png'>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are right, your code should become:

```
if(smilies[words[i]] !== undefined && (typeof smilies[words[i]]) == 'string'){
```

or

```
if(words[i] in smilies && (typeof smilies[words[i]]) == 'string'){
```